# Twig always returns blank page

Tags: php, twig

Hey everybody I am just trying to learn Twig and having a problem getting it to work at all. There are no errors returned in the web server or on the CLI but it just doesn't render the template at all. I installed twig using composer.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
class xltwig {
        private static $twig;
        public static function twig() {
                $templateDir = __DIR__.'/twig/en_us';
                if ( ! isset(self::$twig) ) {
                        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array($templateDir));
                        self::$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
                }
                return self::$twig;
        }
}
$twig = xltwig::twig();
$twig->render("index.html",array('pageTitle' => 'test'));`
```

index.html is simply:

```
<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twig `render` method returns a string with the rendered template content, it doesn't output it. [The documentation shows it used with `echo`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#rendering-templates), and points out:

> The `display()` method is a shortcut to output the template directly.

Comment: Crap that was a typo/goof on my part. I greatly appreciate it.